# Multi-level dropdown navigation - keep secondary dropdown closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, navigation

so I am relatively new to coding and I am trying to make a multilevel dropdown menu, that when opened shows the links for the first level but doesn't show the second level links until clicked.

I started with a fork from codepen and have the navigation built, but I do not know what script to add to close the secondary links.

```js
// open mobile menu
$('.js-toggle-menu').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.mobile-header-nav').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});

$('.sub-toggle').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.subnav1').slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass('open');
});

$('.sub-toggle2').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.subnav2').slideToggle();
});

$('.sub-toggle3').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.subnav3').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .mobile-nav-wrap {
    /* display: none; */
  }
}

.mobile-header-nav {
  background-color: #222222;
  display: none;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.mobile-header-nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.mobile-header-nav li a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
          transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.mobile-header-nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #2f2f2f;
}

a.mobile-menu-toggle {
  padding-left: 50px;
  color: #52575f;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #eeeff0;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <nav class="mobile-nav-wrap" role="navigation">
    <ul class="mobile-header-nav">
      <li> 
        <a href="#" class="sub-toggle">Overview</a>
      <ul class="subnav1">
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="sub-toggle2" href="#">Resources</a>
       <ul class="subnav2">
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="sub-toggle3" href="#">Service</a>
       <ul class="subnav3">
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <a class="mobile-menu-toggle js-toggle-menu" href="#">
   Get Started
  </a>
  
</header>
```

The codepen that I am working on can be found here: 
[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/mcgowanm89/pen/GpOJbx)

Any advice is welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this. The changes are only done to js logic. 
Also, I'm not sure why you have e.preventDefault(). You only need it if you are trying to avoid submit a form. So I took them out.

```
    <header>

  <nav class="mobile-nav-wrap" role="navigation">
    <ul class="mobile-header-nav">
      <li> 
        <a href="#" class="sub-toggle">Overview</a>
      <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="sub-toggle" href="#">Resources</a>
       <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="sub-toggle" href="#">Service</a>
       <ul class="subnav">
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <a class="mobile-menu-toggle js-toggle-menu" href="#">
   Get Started
  </a>

</header>
<script>
$().ready(function()
{
$('.js-toggle-menu').click(function(e){
  $('.sub-toggle').slideToggle();
    $('.sub-toggle').each(function()
    {
        $(this).closest('li').find('.subnav').hide();
    });
});

$('.sub-toggle').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('li').find('.subnav').slideToggle();
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add some CSS to hide the sub nav initially, like this:

```
.subnav1, .subnav2, .subnav3 {
   display: none;
}
```

You may want to also change the classes so they are a little more generic, like just use a class of `subnav` and `sub-toggle` instead of `subnav1`, `sub-toggle2`, etc.  Then you can have just one CSS rule and one event handler regardless of how many menu items you add.  So your CSS for hiding the sub nav would just be:

```
.subnav {
    display: none;
}
```

And your javascript to toggle all of the menu items is reduced to just:

```
$('.sub-toggle').click(function(e){
    $(this).next('.subnav').slideToggle();
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
});
```

I updated your code pen with an example [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rOYxmd).